# PHP form not passing values on POST

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, phpmailer

I have the below html form, which when the user clicks submit, it fires the php code in `contactengine.php` but the values are missing from the email I get and the `.txt` form that is generated.

```
<!------------------from start------------>
  <form method="POST" action="contactengine.php" class="form-inline" >
      <div class="form-group">

       <label>Full Name*</label><br>
        <input name="full_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" id="full_name"   required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Telephone *</label><br>
        <input name="contact_tel" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Telephone" id="contact_tel" required>
      </div>
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Email *</label><br>
        <input name="contact_email" type="email" class="form-control"   placeholder="Email Address" id="contact_email" required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Subject of Enquiry *</label><br>
      <select name="sub_enquiry" class="form-control"  id="sub_enquiry">
            <option value="Assesments" >Assesments</option><option value="Services" >Services</option>
                <option value="Inpections" >Inpections</option>
                <option value="Other" >Other</option>         
      </select>
      </div><br> <br>   
 <label>Your message *</label><br>
      <textarea name="contact_msg" class="form-control" rows="5" id="contact_msg" required  ></textarea> <br >
      <br >
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-purple"  ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Submit</button>
    </form>

<!----------------------php form------------------>
<?php
$to = "xxxx@gmail.com";
$Subject = "OFSUK.ORG";
$full_name = $_POST['full_name']; 
$contact_email = $_POST['contact_email']; 
$contact_tel = $_POST['contact_tel'];
$sub_enquiry = $_POST['sub_enquiry'];
$contact_msg = $_POST['contact_msg']; 

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  header("location:/error.php");
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $full_name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $contact_email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Telephone: ";
$Body .= $contact_tel;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Enquiry: ";
$Body .= $sub_enquiry;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $contact_msg;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($to, $Subject, $Body);
$email_from = $full_name.'<'.$email_from.'>';

$myfile = fopen("emails.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = $Body;
fwrite($myfile, "\n". $txt);
fclose($myfile);

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  header("location:/");
}
else{
 header("location:/contact-us.php");
}

?>
```

These two are stored in two locations but are working fine am just not getting any data.

Comment: Try not to begin your variable names with an uppercase character. Just better coding practice.

Comment: Do `var_dump($_POST);` first of all, please, to make sure your post variables reach PHP.

Comment: Also be aware that you need to filter and sanitize the user input, otherwise your forms will soon enough be exploited by spammers.

Comment: am still getting null values  after using  `$full_name = var_dump($_POST['full_name']); 
$contact_email = var_dump($_POST['contact_email']); 
$contact_tel = var_dump($_POST['contact_tel']);
$sub_enquiry = var_dump($_POST['sub_enquiry']);
$contact_msg = var_dump($_POST['contact_msg']);`

Comment: No, @MarkusAO is saying do `var_dump($_POST);` at the top of your email processing page to see if the `$_POST` has values.

Comment: this is my result, its not passing any data `array(0) { }`

Comment: Is your server properly configured? Can you get any forms to work?

Comment: i bought this script a while back http://codecanyon.net/item/contact-form-generator-form-builder/1719810 it is the only form that seems to be able to send data, its using phpmailer.

Answer (score 0):

Change `<button type="submit" class="btn-purple"/>`

To

`<input type="submit" name="sbmt" class="btn-purple"/>`

And then validate if sbmt has been set, if so print out the values

Comment: am a newbie to php and i keep going back to old code i have sitting around, how would i go about this the phpmail way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

> [pg_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php)

like...

```
pg_escape_string($_POST['full_name']);
```

... to fix data passing problems.

Comment: [`pg_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php) - *"pg_escape_string() escapes a string for querying the database."* - **Note:** - *This function requires PostgreSQL 7.2 or later.* - this isn't db related, so why should they use that?

Comment: Because when 'var_dump($_POST);' didn't return anything in my script this helped.